# Device is not finding a new software update

Tags: device-firmware

I want to update my galaxy tab 4 to Marshmallow or at least Android 5.0.0. I currently have android 4.4, but when I use Kies3, or from the device, it cannot detect that version. Help?
**Edit: This is not a duplicate; that question is something and this is something else. I am asking why I'm not getting the update, that post is an unofficial claim of devices that will get the update. The post doesn't even include my device.**

Comment: Exact model number of your device please? Or atleast the screen size and if it is a 3G/LTE/Wifi only model :)

Comment: @benjaminS SM-T230NU. I want at least Android 5.0

Comment: Quote from the linked question/answer: "Just because a new version has been announced doesn't mean it's immediately available for your device. Even when a particular OS update is announced for your device, it is almost always a phased rollout, meaning that it could be days or weeks from the official release for it to be available for you."